# Im making a jump script for my game, but it won't jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The way my code works is it checks if touching the ground, then if its true, it waits for space to get put in as an input, then if both statements are true, it uses the rigid body method to propel itself into the air.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string objectName;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public int h;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == objectName){
            Debug.Log("On ground statement is true.");
            if(Input.GetKey("space"))
            {
                rb.AddForce(0, h, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i run it, it knows its on ground, but it won't respond to key inputs.
I know it can't be a problem with my computer, as my other controls work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to be testing for player input inside a collision event - if the player is pressing space, it will only ever register during the exact same frame that the object collided with something. A better place for that would be the Update() method, which happens every frame.

You should also create a variable that stores whether the player is currently on the ground or not, based on your collision events. Your input code will check this variable when deciding if the player is allowed to jump.

Try this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string objectName;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public int h;

    public bool onGround = false; // new

    // get your player input in here instead
    void Update()
    {
        if(onGround && Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, h, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == objectName){
            Debug.Log("On ground statement is true.");
            onGround = true; // new
        }
    }

    // new
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == objectName){
            Debug.Log("No longer on the ground.");
            onGround = false;
        }

    }
}
```